# Aparecer um gif de loading ao clicar em um link para gerar um PDF

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um sistema do qual o usuário ao clicar em um link conforme abaixo abre um arquivo PDF:

```
<?php 
  while($listar = mysqli_fetch_object($sql)){ 
?>
    <td class="text-center"><a href="#!" data-id="<?php echo $listar->IdCodCarteiras; ?>" id="link" style="color: #000"><i class="fas fa-address-card fa-lg"></i></a><span id="loading"></span></td>
<?php } ?>
```

Esse link é direcionado para uma página  em PHP onde gera o arquivo PDF através das informações passadas pela variável global `$_REQUEST["key"]`, porém gostaria de saber como faço para que enquanto o arquivo PDF é gerado, apareça um gif de loading ao lado do link clicado pelo usuário.

Pensei em fazer algo assim, mas não tenho muito conhecimento com jquery:

```
$('#link').click(function(){
  $('#loading').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-2x fa-fw"></i>');
  var id = $(this).attr('data-id'); 
  $.post('processar-pdf.php', {key: id}, function(retorno){
  }); 
});
```

Mas não sei se está correto.

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a que melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101).

Comment: Olá Maniero. Ajustei minha pergunta. Acredito que agora ficou mais claro minha dúvida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem várias formas de resolver isso, mas vou separar duas opções..

- A primeira seria aparecer o loading por um determinado tempo, geralmente o tempo medio que demora essa contrução de carteira. (o que não é tão recomendado, mas é simples de resolver)
- A segunda seria enviando uma informação de callback com o tempo de duração do processo (semelhante a quando você vai apagar ou mover uma pasta no seu computador, geralmente aparece, por exemplo: 4 minutos restandtes 130kb de 1000kb.

No primeiro caso você pode fazer isso utilizando javascript:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#build").click((e)=>{
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#build").hide();
      $("#build-loading").show(); 
      setTimeout(()=> {
       $("#build").show();
        $("#build-loading").hide(); 
      }, 5000)
    })
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container-img {
  display: flex;  
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

p, img {
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  margin-bottom: -50px
}

label {  
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#build-loading{
  width: 100px;  
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <td class="text-center">
    <a id="build" href="../../../carteiras/?key=<?php echo $listar->IdCodCarteiras; ?>" style="color: #000">
      <i class="fas fa-address-card fa-lg"></i>
    </a>
  </td>
  <div id="build-loading" class="container-img">    
    <img src="https://media.tenor.com/images/618f1cc8de509138d44a37bfd5e3412f/tenor.gif" width="100" alt=""><label>Construindo...</label>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Basicamente foi feito a ocultação e a desolcutação de itens no html, o qual foi retomado após um tempo que seria o tempo de construição.

Repare que o parametro do ***setTimeout*** é o tempo que dura a contrução em milisegundos.No exemplo foi colocado que o tempo de construção demoraria 5 segundos, use essa [ferramenta](https://www.google.com/search?q=milisegundos%20para%20segundos&oq=milisegundos%20pa&aqs=chrome.1.0l2j69i57j0l3.7943j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) para descobrir o tempo de segundos em milisegundos.

Agora para simular um callback do servidor, vou usar este [json](http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/ceggnTSGDC?indent=2)

```js
var continuar = 0;
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#build").click((e)=>{
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#build").hide();
      $("#build-loading").show(); 
            
      simulandoCallbackApi();                          
    })
});

const simulandoCallbackApi = () => {  
  setTimeout(() => {    
    $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url: "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cfeUYUyUEi?indent=2",      
    }).done(function(data) {
       console.log(data);
       if(data.success){
        $("#build").show();
        $("#build-loading").hide(); 
       }
    });
  }, 1000); 
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container-img {
  display: flex;  
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

p, img {
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  margin-bottom: -50px
}

label {  
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#build-loading{
  width: 100px;  
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <td class="text-center">
    <a id="build" href="../../../carteiras/?key=<?php echo $listar->IdCodCarteiras; ?>" style="color: #000">
      <i class="fas fa-address-card fa-lg"></i>
    </a>
  </td>
  <div id="build-loading" class="container-img">    
    <img src="https://media.tenor.com/images/618f1cc8de509138d44a37bfd5e3412f/tenor.gif" width="100" alt=""><label>Construindo...</label>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Logo a função simulandoCallbackApi representa o processo sendo feito dentro do seu php, e assim que for finalizado é apresentado o botão novamente.

Comment: Muito obrigado Júlio. Usei a segunda opção!